# Magento Up sell alignment issue on the products page

Tags: css, html, magento, alignment

My page: http://www.acuity-sports.com/procage-batting-tunnel-net-42.html

I'm trying to get the upsell to align on the far right side of the page.  The original template had a 2 column left setup and I changed it it a 1column.   It seems like I need to change something to keep it from mashing up to the left side.

After a few hours of looking around I can't seem to find the code I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the span classes have a `float: left` property in the bootstrap style-sheet. To align the "Related products" block in your page to the right side, give a `float: right` to the parent div "span2" of the 'col-upsell-product' div.

Try adding this to your style-sheet

> .yt-product-detail .row .span2{
>       float: right;
>   }

I suggest you add another class name to the div span2 containing the related products, so that the above css property won't apply to any other span2 divs on the page.